# Unable to get ApiVersion working in Web Api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to version my api calls using a tutorial I found at a popular on-line site. I am unable to get the routing to work. I set up two controllers, version 1 and version 2, but I am always routed to version 2. For what it's worth, the code in the tutorial I found seems to have the same problem.

Controller 1:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Http;

namespace WebDemoAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/values")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException("");
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id){return "value";}
        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value) { }
        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value) { }
        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id) { }
    }
}
```

Controller 2:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Http;

namespace WebDemoAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/values")]
    public class Values2Controller : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Values2
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "version2", "version2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Values2/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Values2
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Values2/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Values2/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Web ApiConfig:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.AddApiVersioning(ver =>
            {
                ver.ReportApiVersions = true;
                ver.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                ver.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                ver.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("version");
                ver.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(ver);
            });

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        }
    }
}
```

I attempt to set the header key to version, value to 1.0 but I am routed to the controller for version 2.0. Setting the header value to 2.0 works. Leaving the header key/value out also routes to controller 2.

Comment: How are you testing the calls to this API? It looks like there's something wrong with that because the `CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector` always takes over and routes to version 2.0 of the API.

Comment: @TimoSalomäki Testing using Postman. Are you saying I should remove that property setting in the file?

Comment: I just copied your configuration and everything works fine when I set `Version` header to `1` in Postman. Does thr problem stil persist?

Comment: @Alexander yes, it still persists.

Comment: @Alexander would you post the URI you use from Postman? It's a longshot but maybe I'm not following that part. Otherwise, I'm at a loss.

Comment: So I have copied all your controllers and configurations, and I'm requesting for `/api/values` (using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning` package version `3.0.1`) and I have this result https://prnt.sc/mmpdob

Comment: @Alexander Found the issue. I've worked with .Net since it was in beta. You'd think I would notice the difference between version and Version. But, I didn't. Your comment above with the screen shot is what did it for me. The header key was wrong. I can mark your answer below correct or you can give a second answer that suggests what I did wrong. You found the issue, you just couldn't possibly guess it would be this simple/stupid.

Comment: @Ron Not sure if there is any difference between `version` and `Version` cause I've just tested both in postman and it works fine. I dont really know what you could've done wrong. Anyway I'm glad it's working for you now. I'll just extend my answer.

Comment: @Alexander Well, I did hard resets on the cache each time I changed anything so I don't think it could be that, but whatever works now and I'm happy. Good way to start a week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 predefined version selectors in `Microsoft.Web.Http.Versioning` namespace:

`CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector` selects the latest api version if none is specified in request.
`LowestImplementedApiVersionSelector` selects the lowest api version if none is specified in request.
`ConstantApiVersionSelector` selects constant api version passed in constructor if none is specified in request.
`DefaultApiVersionSelector` selects `DefaultApiVersion` in `ApiVersioningOptions` if none is specified in request.

So if you want `DefaultApiVersion` to be selected by default you need to use `DefaultApiVersionSelector`

```
//or just remove this line since this is a default selector
ver.ApiVersionSelector = new DefaultApiVersionSelector(ver);
```

If the versioning is still not working you probably set `Version` header value in the wrong way or something. You can also check if it works with other version readers such as `QueryStringApiVersionReader`. Update config

```
ver.ApiVersionReader = new QueryStringApiVersionReader("version");
```

and pass version in query string

```
/api/values?version=1
```